# Does $\frac{a_n}{x_n} \approx L$ for sufficiently large $n$ $\implies a_n \approx Lx_n$ for sufficiently large $n$?

Tags: limits, proof-verification, limits-without-lhopital

Given two strictly increasing sequences $a_n$ and $x_n$, is it true that: $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{x_n} = L \implies a_n = L*x_n$$ 
For sufficiently large $n$?  It seems intuitive, given one can simply write state that $\frac{a_n}{x_n}=L$ for sufficiently large $n$, but how might a formal proof of this go?  I think it would begin something like:
$$L-\epsilon \leq \frac{a_n}{x_n} \leq L + \epsilon$$
For $n>0$ and arbitrary $\epsilon \geq 0$.  Then, we have:
$$x_nL-x_n\epsilon \leq a_n \leq x_nL + x_n\epsilon$$
Letting $\epsilon \to 0$:
$$x_nL \leq a_n \leq x_nL  \implies a_n=x_nL$$
Is this proof sound?  If not, what might be the salvage?

Comment: It is certainly *not* true that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{a_n}{x_n}-L\right)=0$ implies $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(a_n-Lx_n\right)=0$ because it is possible that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{x_n}=L$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n-Lx_n=\infty$.

Comment: You need to be precise by what you mean by $a_n \approx L{x_n}$. If $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{x_n} = L$$ this tells you that that the ratio between $a_n$ and $Lx_n$ is approaching $1$. That is to say, the relative error between $a_n$ and $L{x_n}$ is tending to $0$, but not necessarily the absolute error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not true. For example, with $a_n=1-\frac{1}{n}$ and $x_n=1-\frac{2}{n}$, both sequences are strictly increasing and you have $L=1$, but there is no $n$ for which  $a_n=x_n$.